# POST request not working on thread Android

Tags: android, json, multithreading, post

I come up with a bizarre error in my android app, i want to do a POST request to store data in a MySQL database.

But the problem is that the application terminated when i try to do this in a thread and there is no indication in the error, so it's difficult to repair this.

The code is bellow :

```
   thread =  new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
                        URL url = new URL("myurl");
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        connection.setDoOutput(true);
                        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type","application/json");

                        JSONObject jsobj = new JSONObject();
                        jsobj.put("pseudo",edit.getText().toString());
                        jsobj.put("score",score);

                        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                        wr.writeBytes(jsobj.toString());
                        wr.flush();
                        wr.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }catch (JSONException je){
                        je.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();
```

Thank you so much on the help that you will get me :) .

Comment: put your error log here

Comment: it appears that i need internet connection on the device so i have to tell the application that he needs internet

Comment: Of course you need internet permission.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    public class CallWebService extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        String pseudo ="";
        String score="";
        public CallWebService(String pseudo,String score){
            this.pseudo =  pseudo;
            this.score = score;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
                URL url = new URL("myurl");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type","application/json");

                JSONObject jsobj = new JSONObject();
                jsobj.put("pseudo",pseudo);
                jsobj.put("score",score);

                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(jsobj.toString());
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (JSONException je){
                je.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
```

and add below code to execute above asynctask

```
`new CallWebService(edt.getText().toString(),score).execute();`
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for such use case I recommend you to use an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) since 
this is a simple request and AsyncTasks are easier to use.

Second, you are simply sending the request to the server, but not getting the response, thus if the request fails on the server side or you make a bad request you will be unaware of it. You can use [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) to simplify the process.

Comment: This is no answer to the question at all. Please use comments for advices.

Answer (score 0):

add this line before setContentView();

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
 setContentView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, i have find the answer for the problem, we need to add internet permission for the program to work. So we have to add internet permission on your manifest like this :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```